# How to fix "org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist"

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm populating database using hibernate orm and can't pass more than one object.

I've tried using cascade MERGE in object collections, reorganize from oneToMany to manyToMany relations but it seems that the problem does not relate to hibernate...

I have few entities:

Course.class

```
@Data
@Entity
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@Table(name = "course", catalog = "course_application")
public class Course {

    private static final int MAX_COURSES_PER_STUDENT = 3;
    private static final int MODULES_PER_COURSE = 10;
    private @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    Long id;
    private @Version
    int version;
    @NotNull
    private String name;
    @NotNull
    private int number;
    private float cost;
    private int modules;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "course_listeners",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "course_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "listener_id")
    )
    private List<Student> participators = new ArrayList<Student>();

    public Course() {
    }

    public Course(String name, int number, float cost) {
        this.name = name;
        this.number = number;
        this.cost = cost;
    }

    public void addParticipator(Student student) {
        participators.add(student);
    }

    public void addParticipator(Collection<Student> students) {
        participators.addAll(students);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void fill(Course course) {
        this.version++;
        this.name = course.getName();
        this.modules = course.getModules();
        this.number = course.getNumber();
    }
}
```

Student.class

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "students", catalog = "course_application")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Student {

    @ManyToMany(targetEntity = CourseProgress.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "students_progress",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "student_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "progress_id")
    )
    private final List<CourseProgress> progressList = new ArrayList<CourseProgress>();
    private @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "student_id")
    Long id;
    private @Version
    int version;
    @NotNull
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private String phone;
    private Integer gradeBook;
    private float averageProgress;
    @Embedded
    private Advance advance;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "participators")
    private List<Course> courses = new ArrayList<Course>();

    public Student() {

    }

    public Student(String name, String address, String phone, Integer gradeBook) {

        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.gradeBook = gradeBook;

    }

    @PostConstruct
    private void fillGradebookNumber() {
        gradeBook = gradeBook + Math.toIntExact(id);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getName();
    }

    public void addCourseProgress(CourseProgress progress) {
        progressList.add(progress);
    }

    public void fill(Student copy) {
        this.version++;
        this.name = copy.getName();
        this.phone = copy.getPhone();
        this.address = copy.getAddress();
        this.averageProgress = copy.getAverageProgress();
        this.gradeBook = copy.getGradeBook();
    }
}
```

CourseProgress.class

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "progress")
public class CourseProgress {

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "marks", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "progress_id"))
    @Column(name = "mark")
    private final List<Integer> marks = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    private @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    Long id;
    private @Version
    int version;
    private String name;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    private Course course;
    @Column(name = "average", columnDefinition = "Decimal(6,1)")
    private double average = 0.00;
    private int finalMark;

    public CourseProgress() {
    }

    public void addMark(Integer mark) {
        marks.add(mark);
        refreshAverage();
    }

    public void addMark(List<Integer> fewMarks) {
        marks.addAll(fewMarks);
        refreshAverage();
    }

    public void refreshAverage() {

        List onlyMarks = marks.stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
        IntSummaryStatistics stats = onlyMarks.stream().mapToInt((mark) -> (int) mark).summaryStatistics();
        average = stats.getAverage();

    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return course.toString();
    }

}
```

I'm populating database using CommandLineRunner class:

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
public class LoadDatabase {

    @Bean
    CommandLineRunner populateDatabase(
            StudentRepository studentRepository,
            CourseRepository courseRepository,
            CourseProgressRepository progressRepository,
            ExchangeFileRepository exchangeFileRepository) {

        return args -> {

            log.info("Загружаем учащихся");
            Student studentIvanov = new Student(
                    "Иванов Иван Иванович",
                    "100200, Россия, г. Москва, ул. Вознесенская, 15 / ф",
                    "+7(978)111-22-33",
                    1000121);

            Student studentJackson = new Student(
                    "Бобби Джэксон Младший",
                    "100200, Россия, г. Москва, ул. Провансальная, 22 / 11",
                    "+7(978)111-22-33",
                    1000122);

            Student studentCarlson = new Student(
                    "Сэмми Смит Карлсон",
                    "100200, Россия, г. Москва, ул. Ленинская, 8а",
                    "+7(978)222-33-44",
                    1000123);

            Student studentHarris = new Student(
                    "Гарри Дэйл Харрисон",
                    "100200, Россия, г. Москва, ул. Оборонная, 127a / 1",
                    "+7(978)333-44-55",
                    1000124);

            Student studentGomez = new Student(
                    "Линдси Джэфферсон Гомез",
                    "100200, Россия, г. Москва, ул. Суздальская, 200 / 112",
                    "+7(978)555-66-77",
                    1000125);

            Student studentParker = new Student(
                    "Рэйчел Джэксон Паркер",
                    "100200, Россия, г. Москва, Флотский переулок, 1",
                    "+7(978)666-77-88",
                    1000126);

            log.info("Загружаем базовые курсы для студентов...");
            Course chemistryCourse = new Course("Химия для учеников старших классов и студентов", 202554110, 22000f);
            Course physicsCourse = new Course("Углубленный курс физики", 100292910, 25000f);
            Course programmingCourse = new Course("Общий кура подготовки программиста на языке Java Core.", 300235650, 30000f);

            CourseProgress ivanovJavaProgress = new CourseProgress();
            ivanovJavaProgress.setName("Курс программирования Java");
            ivanovJavaProgress.setCourse(programmingCourse);
            studentIvanov.addCourseProgress(ivanovJavaProgress);

            programmingCourse.addParticipator(studentIvanov);

            ivanovJavaProgress.addMark(Arrays.asList(5, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5));

            CourseProgress ivanovChemProgress = new CourseProgress();
            ivanovChemProgress.setName("Подготовительные курсы по химии");
            ivanovChemProgress.setCourse(chemistryCourse);
            studentIvanov.addCourseProgress(ivanovChemProgress);

            chemistryCourse.addParticipator(studentIvanov);

            ivanovChemProgress.addMark(Arrays.asList(2, 3, 2, 4, 5, 3));

            studentRepository.save(studentIvanov);

            CourseProgress jacksonJavaProgress = new CourseProgress();
            jacksonJavaProgress.setName("Курс программирования Java");
            jacksonJavaProgress.setCourse(programmingCourse);
            studentJackson.addCourseProgress(jacksonJavaProgress);

            programmingCourse.addParticipator(studentJackson);

            jacksonJavaProgress.addMark(Arrays.asList(5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 5));

            studentRepository.save(studentJackson);

            log.info("Загружаем тестовый экспортный фаайл" + exchangeFileRepository.save(
                    new ExchangeFile("D:\\export_json_31-03-2019_20_12_58.json", Long.valueOf(1846))));

            studentRepository.save(studentCarlson);
            studentRepository.save(studentHarris);
            studentRepository.save(studentGomez);
            studentRepository.save(studentParker);

        };
    }

}
```

```
studentRepository.save(studentIvanov);
```

works excellent and populates correctly, but the next persisted object

```
studentRepository.save(studentJackson);
```

fails with an exception

I expect my code implementation to work correctly each time i save objeect using orm.

Comment: What exception it is throwing?

Comment: Caused by: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: org.bajiepka.courseApp.domain.Course
Here is the full listing of exception: https://github.com/bajiepka13/ItCollege/blob/master/PersistedObjectException

Comment: I don't have an answer because insert cascades follow complex semantics that I find too confusing and uncertain. I personally used to persist every entity separately, in your case the Course entity. It maybe verbose but it's simpler and it always works.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add @Transactional annotation at a Class or Method level where you save the Student entity.